# is it possible to select element with specific content or attribute in CSS?

Tags: css, cross-browser

Is it possible to select element with specific content?

for example in `#footer` i have multiple  so i can't use `#footer > a {}`

can i select  only that `<a>` if  #footer has `<a herf="#header">Top of Page</a>`, but not all `<a>`

Is there any cross-browser way to select like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your selector would be something like this

```
a[href="yourlink"]
```

This will select one specific link in your footer that has "yourlink" in the href attribute
Is this what you want?

Comment: is it supported in all browser except IE6?

Comment: All modern browsers should support this, except for IE6 ofc

Comment: This style of selection by attribute was developed for using CSS with XML documents. In my experience, unless the file (read: the document being styled by this stylesheet) is served up with MIMEtype `application/xml`, selection in this manner will not be recognized as valid.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS 2.1 or greater, you can use the [Attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors). Most of the popular browsers have already supported this feature, but I.E. 6.0 does not support.

Answer (score 0):

CSS2.1 does support selectors such as [att=”val”], in your case [href="#header"], I don't know how many browsers support those yet, though.

But can't you just mark the desired A's with a dedicated class?

Comment: no because HTML is not in my control it's generated by server side

Comment: The attribute selector is a CSS 2.1 feature not CSS3