# HTML & CSS Form <label> styling

Tags: html, css, forms, label

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is it possible to select element with specific content or attribute in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107648/is-it-possible-to-select-element-with-specific-content-or-attribute-in-css)

basically, I have access to the css for a third party form that I need to style, and the element has no ID so I was unsure of how to use css to style it, as I can't use it's class here is the form code:

```
    <label class="form_label" for="example" style="">email</label>
```

How would it be possible to style this, so it will only apply to those  which have the for attribute equal to example?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can select each label like this, and style it as need be:

```
label[for="example"] {
    color: #5c5c5c;
}
```

Comment: Sure thing, don't forget to accept answers